# How to access execution context from a Spring Batch Step? Error: No context holder available for job scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to set the chunk size of my spring batch job at runtime by injecting it into my step as follows:

```
@Bean
@JobScope
@Qualifier("myStep")
public Step myStep(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['chunkSize']}") Integer chunkSize, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<Object> reader, ItemWriter<Object> writer, Listener listener) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep")
    .<Object, Object>chunk(chunkSize)
    .reader(reader)
    .writer(writer)
    .listener(listener)
    .build();
}
```

But I am getting the following error: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope**

I've done some research online but am not able to understand why I am hitting this exception. I'd appreciate assistance in understanding what this error means and how to resolve it. Thanks!

Comment: Any reason for trying to get the `chunkSize` from the execution context and not from job parameters? How/When are you putting that `chunkSize` key in the execution context?

Comment: I have the chunk sizes defined in a database table for each job that needs to get run. The chunk size gets put into the execution context through a tasklet that runs before this step in the job. I tried to pass the chunk size as a job parameter but I see the same issue regarding the job scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the chunk sizes defined in a database table for each job that needs to get run. The chunk size gets put into the execution context through a tasklet that runs before this step in the job

Here is a quick example which works as expected:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.listener.ChunkListenerSupport;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SO64447747WithJobExecutionContext {

    @Bean
    public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    // TODO get chunk size from table and put in job execution context
                    chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("chunkSize", 2);
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public Step step2(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['chunkSize']}") Integer chunkSize) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .<Integer, Integer>chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)))
                .writer(items -> items.forEach(System.out::println))
                .listener(new ChunkListenerSupport() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeChunk(ChunkContext context) {
                        System.out.println("starting to work on a new chunk of size " + chunkSize);
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step1(stepBuilderFactory))
                .next(step2(stepBuilderFactory, null))
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SO64447747WithJobExecutionContext.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

This prints the following output without the error you mentioned:

```
starting to work on a new chunk of size 2
1
2
starting to work on a new chunk of size 2
3
4
```

> I tried to pass the chunk size as a job parameter but I see the same issue regarding the job scope.

The same approach works without any exception when passing the `chunkSize` as a job parameter:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.listener.ChunkListenerSupport;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SO64447747WithJobParameter {

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public Step step(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, @Value("#{jobParameters['chunkSize']}") Integer chunkSize) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
                .<Integer, Integer>chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)))
                .writer(items -> items.forEach(System.out::println))
                .listener(new ChunkListenerSupport() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeChunk(ChunkContext context) {
                        System.out.println("starting to work on a new chunk of size " + chunkSize);
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step(stepBuilderFactory, null))
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SO64447747WithJobParameter.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addLong("chunkSize", 2L)
                .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    }

}
```

This gives the same output as the first example.

Comment: Thank you for the sample code, I was able to understand what was causing the error. I was using .flow for defining the step sequence in my job, whereas I should have been using .start as you have above. Appreciate the help!

Comment: There is a bug with the `.flow` syntax (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/pull/670) that will be fixed in the upcoming 4.3 release.